# Bean method wrongly called on page leave too

Tags: jsf, primefaces, cdi

In a bean, I use the @PostConstruct annotation on a method.
At the call of the page this method is well executed, but it is also executed when I leave the page!
Do you have an idea ?
Thank you.

The pageAccueilSite page calls the page pageTableauContributeur.
The message "postConstruct: init" is displayed.
Back to the page pageAccueilSite : the message "postConstruct: init" is displayed a second time.

My code :

```
<p:commandLink value="Contributeurs" action="pageTableauContributeur.xhtml"/>


@RequestScoped
@Named
public class ContributeurManagerBean implements Serializable {
@PostConstruct
public void init() { 
    System.out.println("Contributeurs : init");


<p:commandLink action="pageAccueilSite.xhtml">
```

Comment: I improved your title... And how is this bean called. Please make a [mcve]

Comment: `commandLink` is used to POST the server, so your bean, being `@RequestScoped` gets recreated again. Use `h:link` instead to make just GET requests.

Comment: With h: link it works, but a blank screen briefly appears before the called page.
Is there a solution?